# Identify a chip that's very hot on PCB

Tags: hardware

Does anyone recognize this chip by chance?

On the chip it is written:
DEYA
SB86

See picture:

[image]

I can't find anything on the web...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not related to reverse-engineering

Answer (score 4):

Logo : Intersil
DEYA could be ISL9000AIRNNZ see datasheet page 3 of
http://res.ameya360.com/3C/DC/BF/ADE72A0B7B90509FB777F89C72_A.pdf
Good luck

Comment: Intersil is now Renesas:  https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl9000a-datasheet